# tkinter programm opens with cmd

Tags: python, tkinter, cmd

I writed a program with Python 3.5.2 using Tkinter (and IDLE). When I debug it, the window comes up. And the window too, where we can see the Error. But if i don't debug it and open it by double-clicking, the window comes up with cmd. If I close the cmd, my window closes too.

```
win = Tk()
win.geometry("450x500")
win.title(just a title)
win.wm_iconbitmap(just a path)
win.resizable(False, False)
```

How can I fix it? Thanks...

(Sorry for the bad English :) )

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the main Event Loop, which may be fired in debug mode separately. Add in:

```
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have it at the and already.
But making .pyw solved the problem thanks